# SSRS 2016/2012 which is best for complex logic - Stored procedures or MDX

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, mdx, olap-cube

I have 1000 SPs. The complex report has 50 stored procedures , 40 input parameters 400 fields and the users have built some 10,000 intermittent tables. This was created some 10 years ago. Now it is being migrated. What is the best solution

Move business logic from SP to MDM cube and then use MDX to source data or is stored procedure is the only option for very complex procedure as building a PowerBI report is not possible for this complex report

Comment: do you already have a target olap cube or are you suggesting building a cube just for this report?!

Comment: There are so many variables to this, what is the skillset available? What does the business need? How much data is there? Are we talking thousands or millions of rows? What kind of data is this? financial? manufacturing? geographic? What is the requirement from the business?

Comment: In addition, I would suggest looking at other data visualisation tools! Qlikview/QlikSense in my opinion offer a much more robust backend then PowerBI that can include complicated ETL